# How can I "divide " song into instruments in Ableton?

Tags: sound-design, sound, ableton-live

I was searching for answer but I cannot find one (maybe I missed).

Is there any way to "divide" song into instruments (parts)? lets say we have song X which has- drums, lead guitar, rhytmm guitar, bass, vocals and I want see all this parts in ableton seperatly. How can I do it?

Thanks for help

Comment: That isn’t possible but there are website where you can buy the multitrack version of a particular song.

Comment: @Timinycricket - it didn't used to be possible. It now is, though it's not perfect.

Comment: @Tetsujin I stand corrected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the old saying goes, you can't unbake the cake once it's cooked.

But, in terms of "stem splitter" apps, I've found XTRAX STEMS to be fairly impressive and affordable.

https://audionamix.com/xtrax-stems/

Answer (score 0):

Music Rebalance in Isot0pe RX 7, Adobe Audition, Audacity all have functions that you can try to do this. It’s not going to sound perfect though. The old school way to create an acappella from a song was to layer the instrumental on top of the original and invert the phase of the stereo image, and it will remove the beat, leaving only the vocals. This method is terrible though and will leave you with the worst underwater sounding low bit rate mp3.  I’m not sure how any of the new programs and plugins sound nowadays. 3 years ago this feature didn’t even exist. You can always do it manually with EQs, but again, it’s not perfect.